# Setting the value of a textbox in Excel VBA to be the sum of multiple other textbox's

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple text box's that take in numeric values, and I am trying to sum the value of all the textbox's and set it to another textbook but it is not working for some reason. I have attached what I have tried below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```vb
Public Sub SumTotalAmount()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").TextBox5.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").TextBox1+ ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").TextBox2+ ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").TextBox3 + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").TextBox4
End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  a TextBox value is a string, so maybe you need to use something like `CLng()` or `CDbl()` to make sure you're adding numbers and not strings?

Comment: Oh that might be why, in it's current state it just adding the string values so it would become like 1.002.00 instead of 3.00

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you're working with numeric values when trying to add the content of the textboxes:

```vb
Public Sub SumTotalAmount()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        .TextBox5.Value = GetNumber(.TextBox1) + GetNumber(.TextBox2) + _
                          GetNumber(.TextBox3) + GetNumber(.TextBox4)
    End With
End Sub

'Return numeric value from textbox (or 0 if not numeric or blank)
Function GetNumber(objTB As Object)
    Dim v
    v = objTB.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 And IsNumeric(v) Then GetNumber = CDbl(v)
End Function
```

Comment: ... or simply using the `Val()` function to *return a numeric value from textbox (or 0 if not numeric or blank)*.

Answer (score 0):

I have a general solution for this problem, with conditions. The names of the textboxes that we want to sum must have the same initial part of the name, e.g. TextBox1, TextBox2 ... The common part is "TextBox". The adder TextBox should have no same common part, eg "TextBxSum". In a cell of the sheet we call the Function as follows:
=sumTextBoxes(A1;"TextBox";"TextBxSum";NOW())
Its function is twofold: on the one hand it returns the sum to the cell, on the other hand it updates the target TextBox with the sum.
The parameters it accepts are: a) Any cell of the sheet, b) The common initial part of the name of the TexBoxes to be added c) The full name of the target TexBox d) the now() makes the formula respond immediately to value changes
The textboxes are ActiveX objects.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function sumTextBoxes(r As Range, txtBxNameBegin As String, targetTextBoxName As String, volat As Date) As Variant
   Dim ole As OLEObject, tole As Object, ws As Worksheet, v As Variant
   Set ws = r.Worksheet
   For Each ole In ws.OLEObjects
      If ole.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
      'remove both Ucase for case sensitive comparison
         If UCase(Left(ole.Name, Len(txtBxNameBegin))) = UCase(txtBxNameBegin) Then
            v = ole.Object.Value
            If IsNumeric(v) Then sumTextBoxes = sumTextBoxes + Val(v)
         End If
      End If
   Next
   ws.OLEObjects(targetTextBoxName).Object.Value = sumTextBoxes & ""
End Function
```

[image]